# Return tensor by reference from a custom keras layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have created a custom layer called `Node` that inherits from `keras.layers.Layer`, this layer represents a single node in a neural network.

My goal is to have it implemented with the following syntax:

```
n1, n2, n3 = Node(), Node(), Node()

n1(n2) # Connects n2 to n1
output1 = n1.output # activation(n1*w1 + b)

n1(n3) # Connects n3 to n1
output1 # output1 is now activation(n1*w1 + n2*w2 + b)
```

In other words, `Node` stores the outbound connections in an array and `.output` should return the weighted sum of those connections (passing it through the activation function, etc) in a `Tensor` form that updates with future changes.

Is it possible to implement that behavior using the `keras.layers.Layer` class and TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python lists to provide a variable number of inputs, and modify output based on input list length:

The `call` function of the layer would look like:

```
def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
    temp = # Your original computations
    if len(inputs) == 1:
        return temp
    elif len(inputs) == 2:
        return inputs[1] + temp
```

Then, your code would become:

```
n1, n2, n3 = Node(), Node(), Node()
output1 = n1([n2])
output1 = n1([n3, output1]) # Connects n3 to n1
```